# Obj.objects.filter() hangs

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

on my system for one table Obj.Objects.filter() hangs. Hang means python eats 100% of CPU.

virtualenv
Python 3.5.2
Django 2.0.9
Ubuntu (probably 16.04, lsb_release does not work for some reason)
Mysql: mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
mysql-connector-python 8.0.13
country-list 0.1.3

.

I had a small management command to fill the table initially:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    if not Country.objects.filter():
        for code, name in countries_for_language('en'):
            Country.objects.create(code=code, name=name)
            print('%s ' % code, end='', flush=True)
```

which run perfectly for the first time, but not for the second.

Trying to eliminate the strange problem with pdb.set_trace() i found that it hangs here:

```
-> if not Country.objects.filter():
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py(176)__get__()
-> def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
(Pdb) n
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py(177)__get__()
-> if instance is not None:
(Pdb) n
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py(180)__get__()
-> if cls._meta.abstract:
(Pdb) n
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py(185)__get__()
-> if cls._meta.swapped:
(Pdb) n
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py(194)__get__()
-> return cls._meta.managers_map[self.manager.name]
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py(194)__get__() ->
```

-> return cls._meta.managers_map[self.manager.name]

```
(Pdb) n
--Call--
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py(81)manager_method()
-> def manager_method(self, *args, * *kwargs):
(Pdb) n
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py(82)manager_method()
-> return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, * *kwargs)
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py(82)manager_method()-><QuerySet 
[<C...uncated)...']>
-> return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, * *kwargs)
(Pdb) n
--Call--
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py(275)__bool__()
-> def __bool__(self):
(Pdb) n
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site- packages/django/db/models/query.py(276)__bool__()
-> self._fetch_all()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py(1180)_fetch_all()
-> def _fetch_all(self):
(Pdb) n
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site- packages/django/db/models/query.py(1181)_fetch_all()
-> if self._result_cache is None:
(Pdb) n
> /home/lenovo/.virtualenvs/cotw/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py(1182)_fetch_all()
-> self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
(Pdb) n
**HANGS**
```

. Going to the db, **select * from app_country** works without any problem.

Going to the shell i found that:

```
Country.objects.filter() works fine
[c for c in Country.objects.filter(id__lt==101) works fine (100 
results)
[c for c in Country.objects.filter(id__lt==101) HANGS
[c for c in Country.objects.filter(id__lt==110, id_gt=95) works fine (19 results)
[c for c in Country.objects.filter(id__lt==110, id_gt=5) HANGS
```

. To me it seems there' s a 100 result limitation on this table, but i' ve no idea why. Not a real limitation, just something which makes it hang.

My question is what can cause this problem and how do i fix it?

Of course the original management command would work with an additional **.exists()**, but still, it is some weird problem.

Comment: Interesting that trying out with a different table from the same db it has the same result, but with a table from a different db (also different virtualenv) it works fine... .

Comment: You can use `Country.objects.bulk_create([Contry(code=code, name=name) for code, name in countries_for_language('en')])` instead single create

Comment: What does query generate when you do that `[c for c in Country.objects.filter(id__lt==101)`? How much queres?

Comment: Enabling general_log in mysql i got only this line: **2019-10-27T17:01:20.563269Z         4 Query     SELECT `common_country`.`id`, `common_country`.`name`, `common_country`.`code` FROM `common_country` WHERE `common_country`.`id` < 103**

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case. but try using `id__lt=101` instead `id_lt==101`

Comment: Ok, that was a type error. Of course i used single equal signs everywhere.